# DVSA Error in deployment with Serverless - 'Bucket name should not contain uppercase characters'

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm trying to deploy the DVSA Serverless App via Serverless (SLS) and I'm hitting this error:

```
Serverless: Packaging service...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  FeedbackBucket - Bucket name should not contain uppercase characters. Please check provider.s3.FeedbackBucket and/or s3 events of function "FeedbackUploads".

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          linux
     Node Version:              10.21.0
     Framework Version:         1.73.1
     Plugin Version:            3.6.13
     SDK Version:               2.3.1
     Components Version:        2.31.2
```

The repo is here https://github.com/OWASP/DVSA and it looks to be the file https://github.com/OWASP/DVSA/blob/master/backend/src/functions/processing/sls.yml which is causing the issue. With the S3 line - should this be a reference rather than a string? (New to SLS so apologies if this is an obvious question). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is line 26 where the bucket name has caps in it: https://github.com/OWASP/DVSA/blob/b26c8a744293cd192383e4a61e0699563505c5a8/backend/src/functions/processing/sls.yml#L26

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still going through the Serverless docs to figure out what's going on, but is it possible to replace the string with a reference? The bucket it's referring to has a different name which is compliant so if I reference that it might fix things. There are more errors like this behind this one too but this is the first it hits. Thanks!